# What is the difference between model.LGBMRegressor.fit(x_train, y_train) and lightgbm.train(train_data, valid_sets = test_data)?

Tags: python, machine-learning, data-science, lightgbm

I tried out two ways of implementing light GBM. Expect it to return the same value but it didnt.

I thought `lgb.LightGBMRegressor()` and `lgb.train(train_data, test_data)` will return the same accuracy but it didnt. So I wonder why?

## Function to break the data

```py
def dataready(train, test, predictvar):
    included_features = train.columns
    y_test = test[predictvar].values
    y_train = train[predictvar].ravel()
    train = train.drop([predictvar], axis = 1)
    test = test.drop([predictvar], axis = 1)
    x_train = train.values
    x_test = test.values
    return x_train, y_train, x_test, y_test, train
```

## This is how i break down the data

```
x_train, y_train, x_test, y_test, train2 = dataready(train, test, 'runtime.min')
train_data = lgb.Dataset(x_train, label=y_train)
test_data = lgb.Dataset(x_test, label=y_test)
```

## predict model

```
lgb1 = LMGBRegressor()
lgb1.fit(x_train, y_train)
lgb = lgb.train(parameters,train_data,valid_sets=test_data,num_boost_round=5000,early_stopping_rounds=100)
```

I expect it to be roughly the same but it is not. As far as I understand, one is a booster and the other is a regressor?

Comment: My guess is, that `fit` is just the method used by the sklearn api of light gbm (to make light gbm usable in libraries built for sklearn) and `train` is the native method of lightgbm. So the difference is probably just caused by different default values.

Comment: Did you get any insights? I have the exact same doubt.

Comment: I have the same issue, after testing 20 runs on each with same sets of hyperparameters, using sklearn fit alwasys give me better results, I don't understand why

Comment: Unfortunately, lightgbm support team is really weak and they have closed a discussion topic: https://github.com/microsoft/LightGBM/issues/2930. I have the same issue. I have not set any parameters in either of them, but I get a huge difference between the two APIs.

Answer (score 12):

`LGBMRegressor` is the [sklearn](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/) interface. The `.fit(X, y)` call is standard sklearn syntax for model training. It is a class object for you to use as part of sklearn's ecosystem (for running pipelines, parameter tuning etc.).

`lightgbm.train` is the core training API for lightgbm itself.

XGBoost and many other popular ML training libraries have a similar differentiation (core API uses `xgb.train(...)` for example with sklearn API using `XGBClassifier` or `XGBRegressor`).